# SharePoint Online - Filter web part to filter List View web part Created By Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-part, list-view, filter

I have a SharePoint list and Created by (default)column associated to it. I am using List view web part to display this list on a web part page. I want to associate a filter web part and filter values for Created By Column. Which Filter web part should i use to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to give users the option of selecting a filter or are you trying to show what they created?

Comment: This page will be only for my manager.  So if he wants to view items created by some one (Mr X), he should be able to type in a few letters of Mr X name and it should pull all list items created by Mr X.